# Why the values of checked elements from select control are not coming in $_POST array after submission of form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, post

I've following HTML code:

```
<form action="rebates.php" role="form" method="post">
<select id="example28" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states">
    <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
    <option value="1" >Alabama</option>
    <option value="2" >Alaska</option>
    <option value="3" >Arizona</option>
    <option value="4" >Arkansas</option>
    <option value="5" >California</option>
 </select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
</form>
```

The JQuery code for select control is as follows:

```
/*jQuery Code*/
 $(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();
     $('#example28').multiselect({
         includeSelectAllOption: true,
         maxHeight: 150
     });
 });
```

I've used Bootstrap's **js and css (Multiselect and Prettify)** to achieve this. My issue is I'm not getting the checked elements' values after submission of form in `$_POST array` oe rebates.php. Can someone please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance. When I check some values from the select control and submit the form I'm getting the `$_POST` array as follows:

```
Array
(
 [applicable_states] => 11
 [multiselect] => 11
)
```

Why this is happening? 
The code in rebates.php is as follows:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); die;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP needs to know it's an array. So you need to change the name of the select.

```
name="applicable_states[]"
```

Comment: I tried your idea. Changed the name of select control to applicable_states[] but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Did anything change? What does your `$_POST` look like now?

Comment: @It didn't change at all. Looking all the same.

Comment: Dou you have any other idea?